# How to display a table with more than one geometry column in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, geometry

In PostGIS, it is possible to use addgeometrycolumn more than once on the same table.

Example:
I have one table "scenes" with many attributes, and 2 geometry columns: the_geom1 and the_geom2.

```
select addgeometrycolumn('scenes', 'the_geom1', 0, 'POLYGON', 2);
select addgeometrycolumn('scenes', 'the_geom2', 0, 'POLYGON', 2);
```

In QGIS, when I display "scenes", it only displays the_geom1.

To display the features using the second geometry, I found a solution with :

```
create view v2 as select id,the_geom2 from scenes;
```

But I'd like to access all other fields; something like:

```
create view v2 as select * (except the_geom1),the_geom2 from scenes;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If a table has two geometry columns, it is listed twice in the Add PostGIS Table(s) dialog:

[image]

Select the geometry column you want to use and press Add.

Comment: That's quite helpful.
I use QGIS3.4 where 'Add PostGIS Tables' is at 'Data Source Manager' - 'PostgreSQL'

Answer (score 2):

QGIS sees your table two times, one with `the_geom1` and one with `the_geom2`. When you upload `the_geom1`, you will see `the_geom2` like a text and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can load it using DB Manager. Insert the query to SQL Window and load it as layer. Something like this:

```
SELECT id::int, the_geom1, next_attributes... FROM scenes;
SELECT id::int, the_geom2, next_attributes... FROM scenes;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not create two views and drop geometry columns alternatively? Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712243/2308051 (except that you would use views, not tables).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display multiple geometries from the same table at the same time in the same layer but in different ways, you can use a Geometry Generator with the `geom_from_wkt` function on the other geometry column. You may need to strip off the `SRID=xxxx;` string which PostGIS generates but QGIS does not like. For example here I have the solid black line from the geometry column, but the red arrow marker line generated from the column "g2".[image]