# Mangled table names and choice of geometry when there are multiple geometry columns

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have a PostGIS (2.4) table `tt` with multiple `geometry` columns, `geom`, `geom1`, `geom2`. When loaded into QGIS (3.0.1), the table is displayed with the table name plus a geometry column name, such as `tt.geom1`, and the mangled name is now *different* from the true table name in the database.

I tried to avoid the difference by placing the conventional `geom` column before the `geom1` column. But  the same result is the same.

Is there a way to config QGIS to disable the mangling of table names?

-- EDIT --

It is a problem to me because the column chosen by QGIS (`geom1`) isn't the one I wanted to show/use as the geometry (It's `geom` instead). `geom1` contains reference data not intended to be used as the main geometry. I don't seem to have control on which geometric column to use.

Now I need to be careful about having additional geometry columns in PostGIS because of the choices made in QGIS. Would be nice if I can somehow control it or disable it.

Comment: Does it make some trouble for you or is it an inconvenience? I guess some people do like to know which of the geometries they see and edit.

Comment: @user30184 I see your point. I've edited the question to explain.

Comment: Have you also geom and geom2 registered in geometry_columns table?

Comment: So the actual question is how to use geom instead of geom1? See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279246/187

Comment: @underdark Thanks for the link. Yes, now that's the main problem. Another issue associated with the mangled names is that my pyqgis code presently assumes that the layer name is the same as the source table name in PostGIS. The mangled names complicates logic, but I guess that can be circumvented.