# PyQGIS MS SQL table with two geometry columns

Tags: pyqgis, sql

I have a Mircosoft SQL Server database. In a table I need to save two different geometries in a same record (row). Is for this I create two columns. The second one I created adding a column using MS SQL Management Studio (I only add column and I don't do anything more).

When I try to save data in the second column, nothing save in the column (geom_2). I use the same gramatical order to save data in column one (geom).

This works: (column 1)

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(server,"", DDBB, user, password)
uri.setDataSource("dbo",table,'geom')
layer=QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "Open "+table, "mssql") 
layer.selectByExpression(scope,QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
fid = layer.selectedFeatureIds()[0]
values=QgsGeometry() # for simplify I don't put geometry value
layer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({ fid : values})
layer.updateExtents()
```

This doesn't work:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(server,"", DDBB, user, password)
uri.setDataSource("dbo",table,'geom_2')
layer=QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "Open "+table, "mssql") 
layer.selectByExpression(scope,QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
fid = layer.selectedFeatureIds()[0]
values=QgsGeometry() # for simplify I don't put geometry value
layer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({ fid : values})
layer.updateExtents()
```

By the moment I resolve with and SQL order:

```
UPDATE table SET geom_2 = (geometry::STGeomFromText('{}', 0)) WHERE Id=1""".format(geom.asWkt())
```

After that I will need to show this two geometry in QGIS canvas.

[How to display a table with more than one geometry column in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109599/how-to-display-a-table-with-more-than-one-geometry-column-in-qgis)