# Use geometry from a second PostGIS geometry field

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I am trying to use multiple PostGIS geometry fields in a single QGIS layer
In the Data Source Manager, I properly see the two entries, one with Linestring:4326, the other one with Point:4326

When used independently in different layers things are fine, I however want to use the Point geometry information in the Layer imported based on the Linestring geometry. The example provided [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/428328)  covers that case pretty well, but it looks like my geometry data is formatted differently.

I am unable to properly retrieve anything from my Point column 'arrival_position'. When looking at the layers' Attribute table, a geometry is there:
[image]

However, in the Layer Symbology / Geometry Generator editor, the "arrival_position" returns nothing as a geometry nor as a string.
The column is given as Qwidget* / geometry in the attributes table so I tried to use the following:

- "arrival_position" directly, returns nothing in the preview
- geom_from_wkt"(arrival_position"), returns NULL on items that I can actually see OK in the attributes table

And to try to figure out what the "arrival_position" actually provides:

- to_string("arrival_position"), which returns ''
- geom_to_wkt("arrival_position") indicates 'cannot convert to geometry)

How can I actually use this Point(X Y) [EPSG:4326 - WGS84] ?

Comment: You need to modify your WKT to be valid, if you want to add the srid then use EWKT

Comment: @IanTurton: Thanks for your reply. Still not clear to me where I could/would use EWKT. QGIS displays what is shown in my post (WKT followed by the SRID between square brackets). But the actual geomtery format in my PostgreSQL database is WKT : column is defined as Point geometry with SRID defined, and the  column content is WKT (without SRID)

Comment: The [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/428328/84870) is in the answer you have linked, i.e. remove the extra SRID text (`[EPSG:4326 - WGS84]`)

Comment: @JGH: I saw that from the beginning, thanks, it is the first method I tried to apply and to debug as far as I could. But my "arrival_position" variable is not handled as a string, it reports nothing if I try any string related function including that substr() function. Maybe I am missing something obvious but I really don't see.

Comment: I have actually worked arond this issue by creating a text column ST_ASTEXT(arrival_position) with that I get a WKT string that is straightfoward to use in the Geometry Generator. When looking at the additinal 'geometry 'column that I try to use, in the Expression Based Preview samples it shows: POINT(1 1)[EPSG:4326]['']. And if I select a sample, what it collects is the ''. It looks like what I accces in the "closest_arrival" variable is the '' associated to the position reference, not the position itself.